# Controlling size of new window for external link

Tags: java, html

I have a popup on my homepage, and I am happy with the size of that window...I have added a link on the homepage to direct to same popup, but it opens in a full size window.  How do I get the linked file to open in same size window as the popup?

Comment: you want to open popup in JavaScript or Java?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put your code here, so we can see where is the problem and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of the function you're using.

http://dochub.io/#dom/window.open

You can clearly set a height and width there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.open`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function to open a popup window. For example, `window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'height=400,width=300');` to open the window with height set to 400px and width set to 300px.

You can use JavaScript to add the behavior dynamically. Suppose the link's ID is `myLink`.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   window.open(event.target.href, '_blank', 'height=400,width=300');
});
```